# An array that has another array Is it possible to have just one array? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I simplified the code below so it seems dum but the problem I have is since I push the array to another array, the `sample` is an array that has another array.

```
  const sample = [];
  const test = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

  sample.push(test);

  console.log(sample);
```

current sample outcome

```
[["a", "b", "c", "d"]]
```

I just want to have one array and is that possible?

Comment: Try `sample.push(...test)`

Comment: `console.log(test);`?

Comment: Try:  
`sample.flat()`  or 
`sample.flat(depth)` where depth is an int  
See: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked!

```
sample.push(...test)
```